# SharePoint Service Account and Remote SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, web-config

Our custom SharePoint site uses a standard connection string (in web.config) to a remote sql server using a sql server authentication.  I need to know if it is possible to change this connection to use a SharePoint service account instead of a sql server account.  If so, how do specify the service account in the connection string and how do you create a login and user for an sp service account when that user does not exist on the sql server machine and nor is it available on Active Directory.

Update:
I think I need to use integrated security in the connection string and run db calls within SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges block.  If i use this as a delegate, what sp account will the code be executed under and how do i assign a sql server login to a sharepoint account on a remote machine.  Any links to sample code or articles explaining this process would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the SQL Server side, you should create a domain account for Sharepoint in AD. Then you log in to SQL Server via Management Studio (SQL2005 or later), on the left hand side click on security tab, and add a new login - you'll enter the domain Sharepoint service account, and give it the relevant permissions to the databases it needs to access.

For the Sharepoint side, you probably can edit web.config but there must be a Sharepoint admin tool to take care of this properly.